# ORACLE Compound trigger Reference to uninitialized collection

Tags: oracle, triggers

I cant set "global" variable table that would be valid in all coumpound trigger sections.

Simplified example (in my real example I wat to collect some ids and then perform action in AFTER section)

```
create or replace
TYPE couple_ids is table of number;


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trig_on_voice_tags_upd_del
FOR  UPDATE OR DELETE  ON voice_tags
COMPOUND TRIGGER

table_ids couple_ids;

 BEFORE STATEMENT IS
 BEGIN
  table_ids:= couple_ids();
  table_ids.extend;
  dbms_output.put_line('BEFORE STATEMENT size:' || table_ids.count );
  NULL;
 END BEFORE STATEMENT;

 BEFORE EACH ROW IS
 BEGIN

  dbms_output.put_line('BEFORE EACH ROW IS size:' || table_ids.count );
  NULL;
 END BEFORE EACH ROW;

 AFTER EACH ROW IS
 BEGIN

dbms_output.put_line('AFTER EACH ROW size:' || table_ids.count );
  NULL;

END AFTER EACH ROW;

 AFTER STATEMENT IS
 BEGIN

  dbms_output.put_line('AFTER STATEMENT size:' || table_ids.count );
  NULL;
 END AFTER STATEMENT;
END trig_on_voice_tags_upd_del;
```

Unfortunatelly I get **ORA-06531: Reference to uninitialized collection** on line of "dbms_output.put_line('BEFORE EACH ROW IS size:' || table_ids.count );"

Why it is not **table_ids** visible (initialized) in all sections?

Comment: I don't know why, but I would try declaring the collection and initialising at the same time: `table_ids couple_ids := couple_ids();`

Comment: Any difference when you set a value, e.g. `table_ids(table_ids.last) := 1` after `table_ids.extend;`?

Comment: I copied the type and trigger definitions exactly as above, and created a simple `voice_tags` table.  Got no errors at all on either update or delete.  Oracle version 11.2.0.4.

Comment: table_ids couple_ids := couple_ids(); Yes, this helped! I am suprised but this workds.. I have 11.2.0.4 so maybe it is some tricky oracle setup.. @Wernfried - no, no difference.